# PhpStorm add PHP highlighting to .mustache

Tags: php, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

I want to use PHP code in `.mustache` files but PhpStrom highlights only html and js syntax.

How to add PHP syntax highlighting in `.mustache` files?

I have installed Handlebars/Mustache plugin.

Comment: As fas as I'm aware -- no way ATM, unfortunately. 1) In order to have proper PHP syntax/code completion/etc support the file MUST be associated with `PHP ` file type 2) You cannot mix 2 different template languages in one file (PHP and Mustache) (`Template Data Languages` only support "basic" languages but not Templating ones.

Answer (score 0):

1)Just crate a test.mustache file by File -> New File. 
2)Type name "test.mustache"
3)It will ask for the type of file.
4)Select PHP

[image]

Comment: Yeah this will work but I have [Handlebars/Mustache](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6884-handlebars-mustache) plugin and .mustache files are correctly recognised. I want to combine .mustache **and** PHP syntax highlighting.